# Destroying the window

Tags: extjs, event-handling, window, extjs4

I am using ExtJs4.

```
new Ext.Window({
    id: token + '_window',
    animateTarget: token + '_taskbar',  //Button id
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    title: name,
    maximizable: true,
    minimizable: true,
    iconCls: 'basketball-small-icon',
    html: 'This is the <b>' + name + '</b> window',
    listeners: {
        'beforeclose': onWindowClose,
        'minimize': function(){ this.hide(); }
    }
```

Note the button to which the animate target is associated.
Here the onWindowClose is defined as

```
function onWindowClose(t){
var token = t.id.split('_')[0];
var taskBarItemId = token + '_taskbar';

Ext.getCmp(taskBarItemId).destroy(); //Destroying the button
t.destroy();  //Destroying the window
}
```

Here I want to remove the window and the associated button.
Everytime I close the window, I have two choices as below

- I can destroy both the button and the window but sometimes I can't open the window again. I think this has something to do with the fact that the button is linked to window's 'animateTarget'. Because when I remove this property, this works fine.
- I can use t.close() instead of t.destroy(), but it becomes recursive. How can I call the base close method?

Is it a good idea to destroy the window everytime and create using 'new' whenever the icon is clicked?
What is difference between close() and destroy() methods?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you want to reuse the window, with a different content.
So, you should create only one window, that you reuse by updating the html content and calling  show() on this window.
To perform that, you need to add the property `closeAction:'hide'`. This way, your window won't be destroyed when clicking on the close button.

```
test = new Ext.Window({
    id: token + '_window',
    animateTarget: token + '_taskbar',
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    title: name,
    maximizable: true,
    minimizable: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    iconCls: 'basketball-small-icon',
    html: 'This is the <b> imad </b> window',
    listeners:{
        'beforehide':function(win){
            Ext.getCmp(win.animateTarget).hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Then, you add this listener to your buttons :

```
    listeners:{
        'click':function(){
            var token = t.id.split('_')[0];
            var targetWindow = Ext.getCmp('token + '_window);
            targetWindow.body.dom.innerHtml = 'Your new html !';
            targetWindow.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call destroy() since once the window is closed, it is automatically destroyed. 
See api of [Ext.Window](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-close).  
And do not call close() in your beforeclose handler since it's already about to close.

I think you can use 'new' whenever you want to create a window and close it either click on the close header tool(top right) or call its close() method. Don't worry about destroy. Ext will do it.

The main difference between close() and destroy() is close fires 'beforeclose' event and decide whether to close the window or hide it based on config option 'closeAction'. If it decides to close, destroy() will be called.

**EDIT:**
try the following

```
function onWindowClose(t){
    var token = t.id.split('_')[0];
    var taskBarItemId = token + '_taskbar';

    Ext.getCmp(taskBarItemId).destroy(); //Destroying the button
    //t.destroy();  //Remove this statement.
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT2:** Remove minimize listener

```
listeners: {
    'beforeclose': onWindowClose//,
     //'minimize': function(){ this.hide(); }
}
```

Comment: do you want me not to include t.close() or t.destroy().

Comment: @Shashwat don't you click on the 'x' button at top right to close the window? Then yes, you needn't call close() or destroy().

Comment: Do you want me not to include t.close() or t.destroy()? It does not work. It removes the button but not the window and the window gets stuck.
I think t.close() will be fired if I call base method close() in the handler. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: its still not working... giving the same problem...
it removes the taskbar button but halts the window...

Comment: @Shashwat try removing the 'minimize' listener. When I have this listener, the second created window will get stuck will it's closed. And please make sure `Ext.getCmp(taskBarItemId).destroy();` won't cause a javascript error. I don't know what it is so i commented it out.